# Cursor loader not working after fragment is detached

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-cursoradapter, android-loader

using PagerSlidingTabStrip to render fragment in tabs

```
@Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            if (position == 0)
                return new FlipActivity();
            else if (position == 1)
                return new CategoryFragment();
            else if (position == 2)
                return new PeopleTabFragment();
            else if (position == 3)
                return new MessageTabFragment();
            else if (position == 4)
                return new HistorytabFragment();
            return new SuperAwesomeCardFragment().newInstance(position);

        }
```

PeopleTabFragment uses cursor adapter to read contact from phone and display. The problem is, this only work on the first time. When I select other tabs and come back to select the people tab again, the listview becomes empty. Snippet is below.

```
public class PeopleTabFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
PeopleAdapter peopleAdapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_layout, container, false);
    StickyListHeadersListView listView = (StickyListHeadersListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
    getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, savedInstanceState, this);
    peopleAdapter = new PeopleAdapter(getActivity(), null, CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
    listView.setAdapter(peopleAdapter);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(), ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, "upper(" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + ") ASC");
    return cursorLoader;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    peopleAdapter.load(data);
    peopleAdapter.swapCursor(data);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    peopleAdapter.swapCursor(null);
}
}
```

and this is the adapter

```
public class PeopleAdapter extends CursorAdapter implements StickyListHeadersAdapter {

ArrayList checkerList = new ArrayList();
LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

public PeopleAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
    super(context, c, flags);

    mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}


public void load(Cursor c) {
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        checkerList.add(name);
    }
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.people_item, parent, false);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
    TextView nameTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.contactImage);
    String uri = cursor.getString(cursor
            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI));
    try {
        imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(uri));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        imageView.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    }
    nameTextView.setText(name);
}

@Override
public View getHeaderView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    FunctionHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new FunctionHolder();
        convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.people_header, viewGroup, false);
        holder.functionButton = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (FunctionHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    //set people_header text as first char in name
    String headerText = "" + checkerList.get(position).toString().subSequence(0, 1).charAt(0);
    holder.functionButton.setText(headerText);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public long getHeaderId(int position) {
    return checkerList.get(position).toString().subSequence(0, 1).charAt(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure but can you please try destroying your loader in onLoadFinished() by using

```
getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().destroyLoader(int id);
```

This 'int id' is the integer value you pass in 'initLoader'. For readability, use some value greater than 0.